# Django - Disable Cache key warnings

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am currently designing a Django application and set up a database cache, increased the key size to 500 characters, however I constantly receive this warning:
CacheKeyWarning: Cache key will cause errors if used with memcached: key_text (longer than 250)

Reading through the documentation here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/cache/

*If you are using a production backend that can accept a wider range of keys (a custom backend, or one of the non-memcached built-in backends), and want to use this wider range without warnings, you can silence CacheKeyWarning with this code in the management module of one of your INSTALLED_APPS.*

I've created management folder in my app (tried various places) and added the code required inside it as management.py but it's not working. Has anyone managed to silence these warnings and can please share where they added it? Thanks

Comment: You should be able to ignore these warnings - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/cache/#cache-key-warnings

Answer (score 0):

Here's the TLDR answer, using the `RedisCache` backend (all other backends should work the same way). Update the folder/project names as needed:

In `your_project_folder/YOUR_PROJECT/cache.py`:

```
from django.core.cache.backends.redis import RedisCache

class RedisCache(RedisCache):

    def validate_key(self, key):
        """
        Custom validation, raising exceptions or warnings as needed.
        """
        pass
```

In `settings.py`:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'YOUR_PROJECT.cache.RedisCache',  # use our "new" cache backend
        'LOCATION': 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0',  # example location (use your existing settings)
    }
}
```

Slightly longer answer:

Django natively supports a variety of cache backends (`RedisCache`, `LocMemCache`, etc). Each backend extends the [`django.core.cache.backends.BaseCache`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/4.1.x/django/core/cache/backends/base.py) class, which validates keys in a memcache-friendly way so as to ensure "portable code":

```
def validate_key(self, key):
    """
    Warn about keys that would not be portable to the memcached
    backend. This encourages (but does not force) writing backend-portable
    cache code.
    """
    for warning in memcache_key_warnings(key):
        warnings.warn(warning, CacheKeyWarning)
```

Because the other backends do not override this functionality, we have to override it ourself with the empty method seen in the first code block at the top of this answer.

**Note: Bypassing these warnings will prevent your keys from working in memcached.** This is not an issue for me personally, but the Django developers are clearly nudging developers towards code that works for all cache backends.

This is all explained in the Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/cache/#cache-key-warnings), but the docs fail to explicitly mention that it's okay to pass an empty `validate_key` method. (Before looking, I had wrongly assumed that the default Redis implementation would have some rules that I needed to preserve.)